# crawling inside a for loop is not synchronous

Tags: scrapy

[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCTur.png)

```js
 for hotel in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"sr_item")]'):

            hotelName = hotel.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"sr-hotel__name")]//text()')
            print hotelName.extract()


            hotel_image = hotel.xpath('.//img[contains(@class, "hotel_image")]//@src')
            print hotel_image.extract()


            hotelLink = hotel.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"hotel_name_link")]//@href')


            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(hotelLink[0].extract()), self.parseHotel)


        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"paging-next")]//@href')
```

My code can be seen attached as an image. As, you can see, inside the for loop. I want Scrapy to return from the function "hotelParse", then continue, executing the for loop.

However, now, it firsts prints all the hotel names, meaning, the for loop get executed completely, then "hotelParse" starts yielding.

This would mess up my output, once, I start assigning values to the item object.

Comment: there is no `hotelParse` method in your code

Comment: scrapy is [asynchronous](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#event-driven-networking), so I think you'll have to check a better way to deal with your items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost definitely what you're trying to do is the "Passing additional data to callback functions" from [the Scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions). Here's how it would look for your case:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

    for hotel in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"sr_item")]'):
        item = HotelItem()

        hotelName = hotel.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"sr-hotel__name")]//text()')
        print hotelName.extract()
        item["hotelName"] = hotelName

        hotel_image = hotel.xpath('.//img[contains(@class, "hotel_image")]//@src')
        print hotel_image.extract()
        item["hotel_image"] = hotel_image

        hotelLink = hotel.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"hotel_name_link")]//@href')

        request = scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(hotelLink[0].extract()), self.parseHotel)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

    next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"paging-next")]//@href')
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page.extract()), self.parse_item)

def parseHotel(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item["extra_1"] = response.xpath('/example/text()').extract_first()
    item["extra_2"] = response.xpath('/example2/text()').extract_first()
    yield item
```